# Get only Nic name similar to a particular string in Azure CLI

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-cli

This command gives all NIC names in the Resource group

```
az network nic list --resource-group "RG_TEST" --query "[0].name"
```

I want to get only NIC names contains the below string

String: NIC_PROD_TEST

Comment: Would be much easier to work with PowerShell cmdlets: `Get-AzNetworkInterface -Name '*NIC_PROD_TEST*' -ResourceGroupName 'RG_TEST' `.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After my workaround around this, I was able to retrieve results for a particular string by using the below query.

Eg: ***String: 'new'***

Use ***"query "[?contains(name, 'string')].name"*** as shown below:

```
az network nic list --resource-group <resourcegroupName> --query "[?contains(name, 'new')].name"
```

***Output:***

[image]

If you want to get nic name starts with a particular string, you can use

*"query "[?starts_with(name, 'string')].name"*

```
az network nic list --resource-group <resourcegroupName --query "[?starts_with(name, 'new')].name"
```

*Output:*

[image]

*Reference:* [MSDoc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/query-azure-cli?tabs=concepts,bash#jmespath-functions)